# Merge aliasByNode and aliasByMetric in Grafana backed by Graphite

Tags: graphite, grafana

I want to label series by hostname + metric name. I know I can use `aliasByNode(1)` to do first part and `aliasByMetric()` to do the second. Any ideas how can I merge those two functions in a single metric?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[aliasByNode](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.aliasByNode) can take multiple arguments.

```
aliasByNode(apps.fakesite.web_server_01.counters.requests.count, 2,5)
```

returns `web_server_01.count`.

The Grafana query editor for Graphite does not support this but if you toggle edit mode then you can edit the raw query. After editing it, you can toggle back.

[image: Toggle Edit Mode]

[image]

[image: End Result]

Comment: Latest grafana allows just to type 2, 5.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to check out [aliasSub](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.aliasSub), which allows you to use a regular expression replacement to modify the series name.

In grafana syntax something like `aliasSub(([^.]+)([.][^.]+)*[.]([^.]+), \1 \3)` should do what you're after.

Comment: I'm aware of aliasSub but it's really complex comparing to what I want to achieve. It looks like a standard usecase and it's hard to belive there is no such solution out of the box

Comment: aliaSub is very tedious but wouldn't have been had this type of regex worked:

aliasSub( '(?:([^.]+)\.)+', \0 \1 \2 \3 \4 \5 etc)   That is, have one nested capture that just captures every dot delimited string with a single capture grouping. You could use that same regex everywhere for a more printf like Grafana alias method. I haven't been able to get that to work. Maybe someone else has. The weird ?: thingy is Perl regex way of saying "group this, but don't capture it". I only want to capture the ([^.]+) part but multiple instances, thus the outer grouping is needed with its own + sign.

Answer (score 3):

Something that would solve ALL these problems would just be to have a string with replacement parameters for the metric nodes, like,

```
aliasByVars("core.app.city.rack.app.instance.thread", 
  "resource: city-$3,rack-$4")
```

You could intersperse static text with the values of the metric elements (nodes) all you wanted.

That could replace `alias`, `aliasNode`, `aliasMetric` and 99% of `aliasSub` with one simple, easy to understand namer.

There would be some `aliasSub` applications where you used partial node names this could not replace.

Comment: Great idea! Can you [file a feature request](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/new)?

Comment: Did you ever get around to filing that feature request?